# Railo is caching my cfc's and templates

Tags: caching, cfc, railo, cfcache

I'm currently developing a cfc in railo.

Every time I make a change to the cfc, I have to go into the admin and clear all four caches in order for me to see any changes.

Under Settings > Performance/Caching, Inspect Templates is set to always.
Under Archives & Resources > Components, I have the cache checkbox unchecked.

These settings are set both under the Web.cfm and Server.cfm areas.

In the area I'm working in, the only files are a blank Application.cfm and an index.cfm with a service.cfc, neither of which are calling the `<cfcache>` tag.

What can I do to stop this caching for now?

I'm using Railo 3.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your **Mappings** - make sure the Inspect Templates option is set to "always" for all relevant mappings.

This option is independent of the global Inspect Templates option. (Allowing you to cache, for example, mappings for frameworks that are rarely updated, whilst keeping changing mappings uncached.)

Comment: I don't have any additional mappings on this server (not under the Mappings area) however I do have an additional resource defined under the Component section. Setting the Trusted flag to unchecked for that additional resource seems to have solved the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. What does the trusted flag actually do? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Trusted is as in "Trusted Cache" (CF's name for it), which is the same as Inspect Templates=Never

It used to be the mappings page option was labelled "Trusted" too, but the ambiguous meaning caused people to tick it when they didn't really want to, so it was switched to inspect always/never.

I guess the Additional Resources section was initially overlooked when this change was made, however I've just checked the latest bleeding edge version (3.3.2.009) and it has been updated to inspect there (i.e. same as mappings page now).